# Dependent tensor product in the category of abelian groups

Tags: category-theory, abelian-groups, type-theory

In the category of set (or more generally an arbitrary locally cartesian closed category), we can think of a dependent product $\prod_{I}X$ of a "type family'' $X\to I$ index over $I$. For example, For a map $X\overset{\varphi}\to 2$ where $2:=\{0,1\}$ denotes a two pointed set, $\Pi_2X$ is (isomorphic to) the set $\varphi^{-1}(0)\times\varphi^{-1}(1)$.

The question is, can we consider this in a category $\mathbf{Ab}$ of abelian groups?
Of course $\mathbf{Ab}$ is not an LCCC and does not have a dependent product in the above sense. But can we consider the tensor version?

I.e., for a map $X\to I$ in $\mathbf{Ab}$, can we create an object $\bigotimes_I X$ such that $\bigotimes_{\mathbf{Z}\oplus\mathbf{Z}} X \cong X_1\otimes X_2$ where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are defined by the pullback along $i_1,i_2:\mathbf{Z}\to\mathbf{Z}\oplus\mathbf{Z}$.

And how about other SMCs, e.g. the category of chain complex?

Comment: In abelian groups it’s not really the case that a map $X \to I$ has an interpretation in terms of families of abelian groups (e.g. its set-theoretic fibers are not abelian groups). It’s not at all clear whether one can meaningfully talk about a family of abelian groups indexed by another abelian group.

Comment: The interpretation of dependent type theory in a LCCC is "actually" happening not in the category itself but in its codomain fibration. It just so happens that one can "$\beta$-reduce" the concept of codomain fibration away and talk directly about pullbacks or whatever. The codomain fibration has very good properties over, say, a topos, but it is not so good over an abelian category. (Not _bad_ either – the codomain fibration over an abelian category can interpret regular logic!)

Comment: A better structure to look at is the module fibration over the category of commutative rings, or the quasicoherent sheaf fibration over the category of schemes. These should support an interpretation of dependent linear type theory.